# Edit stay-in-touch template

Tags: email, massemailmessage

I would like to use Salesforce stay-in-touch feature to get our clients to update their details.
I would like to know is it possible to alter the template for Mass Stay-in-touch emails in Salesforce? 
I would like to include company branding to the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to customize Stay-in-Touch.

People have been asking for 8 years, and you can add your vote:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrpvAAC